# Why does subsetting a list from an out-of-range index return an empty list, rather than throw an exception?

Tags: python, list

Say I have the following list:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

If I choose some arbitrary index, for example, 3, and then do a subset:

```
l[3:]
```

The result is `[3, 4]`

However, if I choose a start index > len(l) (eg `l[6:]`), I get the following result:

```
[]
```

Why do I get an empty list, rather than an exception? If I tried `l[6]`, I would get:

> IndexError: list index out of range

What is going on here? What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why substring slicing index out of range works in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python)

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033201/python-index-out-of-range-in-list-slicing) has a more concise answer than the original question it duplicated